# What is the intersection of real numbers' set and span $\{\sin^2x,\cos^2x\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know intersection of real numbers' set and span $\{\sin x,\cos x\}$ is $\{0\}$.
Here in this problem $\sin^2x,\cos^2x$ are linearly independent like as $\sin x,\cos x$ .
If $a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x=k$, which is not equal to $0$.
Then this is absurd.
So $a\sin^2x+b\cos^2x=0$, since $\sin^2x,\cos^2x$ are linearly independent also.
Hence the answer is $\{0\}$.
But my book says it is real numbers' set.
Why? I don't understand.
Please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am interpreting this as taking place within $\scr{C}^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, i.e.  the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If we do  that, then we view $\mathbb{R}$ as being identified with the subspace of constant functions. Now, $\operatorname{span}(\cos^2 x,\sin^2 x)\cap \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$ because as functions, $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$. So, taking any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we get $\lambda\cos^2x+\lambda \sin^2x=\lambda$. So, $\mathbb{R}\subseteq \operatorname{span}(\cos^2x ,\sin^2x)\cap \mathbb{R}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Hence, 
$$ \boxed{\operatorname{span}(\cos^2x,\sin^2x)\cap \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}.}$$

Comment: @M.Nestor: The span itself is not $\{0\}$ (after all, it contains both sine and cosine themselves). However its intersection with the real numbers (interpreted as constant functions, as in the answer above) is.